# Why The Runtime and the timeit is different in my code in python?

Tags: python, performance

I wrote below code and try to see how fast my function is. I used `timeit`.
The factorial result prints very fast (less than 1 sec) but the timer (`func_to_measure()`) shows 3.3 seconds.

Please help me to understand why these are totally different. I thought the run time of `print(factorial(N))` and `Func_to_measure()` would be exactly the same.

```
import sys
from timeit import default_timer as timer
sys.setrecursionlimit(10**6)

print("Please enter the number for factorial:")
n=input()
N=int(n)

def factorial(N):
    #print("factorial has been called with n ="+ str(N))
    if(N==0):
        return(1)
    else:
        res=N*factorial(N-1)
        #print("intermediate result for ",N,"* factorial(",N-1,"):",res)
        return res

print(factorial(N)) # it will print very fast(less than 1 second)

def func_to_measure():
    result=factorial(N)

print("starting timer")
start=timer()
for i in range(100000):
    func_to_measure()
end=timer()
elapsed=end-start

print("elapsed time:",elapsed,"secs") # show after 3 seconds
```

Comment: Aren't you running `factorial` 100000 times between `start` and `end`?  Why would that take the same amount of time as printing the output of one call to `factorial`?

Comment: Oh, I get it. so it cannot be same time becuase I run it for 100000 times not one time.right?

Comment: yep.  you could divide elapsed by 100000.0, and see if that is consistent with what you observe for the speed of the single print